# how to remove .selectable from element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I am working with jquery selectable on one of my tables and I am looking to remove the `.selectable` from the element in certain circumstances.

I had found a solution that I could use that worked and that was to add the option of disabled true or false and use that in if and else statements.

```
$( ".standard-table").selectable({
            filter: "tr",
            disabled: false,
            scrollSnapX: 5, // When the selection is that pixels near to the top/bottom edges, start to scroll
            scrollSnapY: 5, // When the selection is that pixels near to the side edges, start to scroll
            scrollAmount: 25, // In pixels
            scrollIntervalTime: 100 // In milliseconds
});
```

However there was a downside in the fact that I wanted jquery selectable to be gone so I could interact with the table in other ways.

When I disable the Jquery selectable it does the job of not selecting the tables like I wanted to but it prevents me triggering any events on the table whilst it is disabled.

I figured instead of adding the disabled option that I could remove `.selectable` from `.standard-table` when I liked and put it back when I liked.

Is this possible? Or is there another way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove selectable using the [destroy method](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#method-destroy):

```
$( ".standard-table" ).selectable( "destroy" );
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thankyou so much. I can't believe I missed that in the documentation either.